# Separating Data in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I receive data which is numbered consecutively but under each number there is zero, 1 , 2 or 3 pieces of information before the next number. I need to separate the data so that the numbers are evenly spaced! 
Any help would be greatlyfully received - I should have done Excel at University but that was decades ago!
Thankyou,
Graeme
Hi Robert,As a Australian new user I am not allowed to insert images! Hence imagine each comma as separating cells and a dash as an empty Excel cell with the first row what I initially receive. The "g,h" etc are sentences. The 2nd row is what I would like to achieve. Unfortunately it wont format to show the cells going down not across so it has to be across here as it would in Excel or an inserted image!  Thanks!

Receive 1,g,h,2,k,3,a,c,v,4,5,r,t

Require 1,g,h,-,2,k,-,-,3,a,c,v,4,-,-,-,5,r,t,-,

Hence if I received 3 pieces of information for each "number" (client) the numbers would automatically be evenly spaced but this unfortunately does not occur!

Comment: Could you clarify this with an example, showing both what you receive and what it is that you want in the end?

Comment: Hi Robert,As a new user I am not allowed to use images. Hence imagine each number and letter as a separate Excel cell! Thanks!

Comment: I know how frustrating it was when I wasn't allowed to upload pictures or even comment on pages....

Comment: Graeme, Just a question? Are those missing items represented by a space or other (hidden) character that is not recognized in Excel? Could you check the "source" in e.g. a hex-editor. And Uh.. I know you asked for a formula, but I can't think of a solution in a formula to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I will put it in a macro and see how we go as my knowledge of VBA is not good. And YES the dash does represent a totally blank cell. Graeme

Comment: worked brilliantly Robert for the example but my data goes down rather than across but I should be able to solve that!!!

Comment: And solved that too! Great stuff - Merry Christmas from Australia Robert

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be able to help! X-mas greetings from the Netherlands as well.

Answer (score 0):

Graeme, let me know if you can create VBA Macro's based on an example.

I just wrote one that does the job, although being far form elegant.

<-----------CODE START--------->

```
Sub uniformdata()
    ReceiveCol = 1    'Column where received data starts
    ReceiveRow = 1    'Row where where received data starts
    PublishCol = 1    'Column where Published data starts
    PublishRow = 2    'Column where Published data starts
    Do Until Cells(ReceiveRow, ReceiveCol).Value = ""
        For counter = 1 To 4
            If counter = 1 Then
                Cells(PublishRow, PublishCol).Value = Cells(ReceiveRow, ReceiveCol).Value
                ReceiveCol = ReceiveCol + 1
            Else
                If IsNumeric(Cells(ReceiveRow, ReceiveCol).Value) Then
                    Cells(PublishRow, PublishCol).Value = "-"
                Else
                    Cells(PublishRow, PublishCol).Value = Cells(ReceiveRow, ReceiveCol).Value
                    ReceiveCol = ReceiveCol + 1
                End If
            End If
            PublishCol = PublishCol + 1
        Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

<---------CODE END--------->

What it does is to go through your list from left to right until it finds an empty cell. Inside it constantly runs a loop for 4 times. On the first pass it assumes that your number is there, and immediately writes it. On the other 3 passes, it checks if the next received cell is a number or not. If it is a number it knows to fill in the gap with a dash, if it is not a number the character found is used.

Let me know if this solves your issue. In my example, it worked like a charm.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: Actually, I could remove the publishCol + 1 from the individual if statements and move just one of them down at the end of the for next loop.....